# How do you increase hard drive space on an Intel hardware RAID 1 with larger disks?

Tags: raid, raid-1, hardware-raid

I have an old RAID 1 volume from about 7 years ago. A while ago I replaced one out of two drives with a drive with 4x the size and then recently I replaced the second two out of two disks. Both of the two new disks are 4x the size of the original RAID 1 volume.

I read on SuperUser/Server Fault/Stack Exchange question that you can increase the size of the RAID 1 volume but the process is different for every make/model (difference for software/hardware and different for which specific software/hardware you have).

For Intel motherboard/hardware RAID controller and a RAID 1 volume and two new hard drives with more storage, how do you increase the size of the RAID 1 volume?

Answer (score 2):

During the BIOS boot cycle you should be presented with the option to enter into the RAID settings. From there you should be able to extend the size and then grow the filesystem once it's booted back up.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used Intel's GUI application that runs on Microsoft Windows to increase the harddrive size. Most of the Intel motherboard/hardware raid controllers use the same Intel GUI application. The older version is called Intel "Matrix Storage Console" and the newer version are called Intel "Rapid Storage".

Open the GUI application and then make sure it is in "Advanced Mode":

- pulldown menu `View --> Advanced Mode`.

In the advanced view you will see a [tree-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_view) display of all the hardware managed by the sata/raid controller. You need to locate your raid-volume in that tree-like display. In my case my raid volume was located at:

- `Intel Matrix Storage Manager --> Intel ... SATA RAID Controller --> Arrays --> Array_0000 --> Volumes --> Volume0` *1

Then you need to use the GUI to increase the size of the raid-volume by following this process:

- backup all your data
- try to ensure reliable power for 6+ hours
- `right-click the raid-volume --> select Modify-Volume --> Next --> Next --> check the "Volume Capacity Expansion" checkbox --> select the "Utilize 100% of available array space" radio button`
- keep hitting next and confirm your selection

[image: screenshot to show what the "Volume Capacity Expansion" looks like]

After you confirm this GUI dialog, the raid controller will get to work.

NOTE:

- You can view the status of the operation by left-clicking on the volume and looking for "Status" and you will see a percentage completed like this screenshot:

[image: screenshot to show what the status looks like]

- you can still do all the things you want in your OS while the raid-controller is busy but I think performance will be degraded (similar to when the raid-controller has to rebuild the raid-volume)

The last step is:

- wait for 100% status

  - make sure power to the machine is reliable/constant
  - This operation can take a long time. In my case, I was expanding a 230 GB to 1TB and it took 6+ hours.
- restart your machine
- open your favorite disk management application

  - in Windows you can use `Start Menu --> Computer Management --> Disk Management` (linux has many command-line/GUI. one is `gparted`.)
- the disk management application should now show that the disk size is larger (corresponds to however large your new disks are... in my case 1TB) and the larger space should be "unused"
- ***done!***

Bonus, extend the partition:

- if you have a Windows NTFS filesystem for the partition

  - I used `Disk Management` to extend the partition `right-click the partition --> click "Extend" --> confirm`
  - verify the new partition size by going to `My Computer --> right-click the drive "Properties"` there should be more space (in my example I now have 1TB)
- if you have non-NTFS filesystem then the process is different for each type of partition

---

---

*1
Depending on how you created your raid-1 volume, the name/location will vary (finding your would probably be a new question). But if you only have one volume then finding it shouldn't be too hard.