# Increase RAID 1 volume size with Intel RST on system drive

Tags: windows-7, raid, resizing

I need to increase RAID 1 volume size over Intel RapidStorageTechnology on system drive - **question is will it delete any data**??

RST itself didnt show any warning or confirmation on this, I need to expand partition size on work server main RAID 1 volume (swapped HDDs from 160GB+1TB to 1TB+1TB).
System is Win 7 Pro 64bit,

Anyone has already done this??

RST Screenshot:

[image: RST Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for cooperation, 
it worked exactly as we expected, Intel RST increased the size of the RAID volume(with both hard drives connected and rebuilded) which took a few hours, then I had to extend main partition through Windows Disk Management and thats it, worked without any data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You won't loose data on Raid 1

[Here is the instructions](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000005837/technologies/intel-rapid-storage-technology-intel-rst.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I did it this way (larger drive is already attached, raid array already rebuilded, RST is offering size increase within Windows GUI), will it stay intact? Thanks

https://superuser.com/questions/1019935/how-do-you-increase-harddrive-space-on-an-intel-hardware-raid-1-with-larger-disk

Comment: What step are you up to?

Comment: RAID rebuilded with two 1TB drives, system working, but partition size is stil only 160GB.